# kotlin: ignoring return type of let function?

Tags: syntax, kotlin

I can create same function with 2 different return types and i get no compilation error no matter which version i choose. is it a bug or some language feature?

```
fun unitOrInt(): Int  { return 1.let { 1 }}
fun unitOrInt(): Unit { return 1.let { 1 }}
fun unitOrInt()       { return 1.let { 1 }}
```

the type of `1.let{1}` is `Int` not `Unit`. why `Unit` version is allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `let` function is generic, its [signature](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) is `inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R`. When you call this function, the compiler infers the type parameters from enclosing context.

In the first declaration of the function, the compiler knows that the expected type of the call is `Int`, so it infers the R type parameter to be `Int`, and finds a value of a matching type as the last expression of the lambda. In the second declaration, the expected type is `Unit`, so the compiler infers R as `Unit` and ignores the last expression of the lambda. In the third declaration, there is no return type declaration, so the compiler substitutes `Unit` and analyzes it like the second declaration.

To better see what's happening, you can declare the type parameters of `let` explicitly:

```
fun unitOrInt1(): Int  { return 1.let<Int, Int> { 1 }}
fun unitOrInt2(): Unit { return 1.let<Int, Unit> { 1 }}
```